# How to remove everything from string after the last character?

Tags: javascript, string

I am practicing and I wrote length of last word in JS.

```
var lengthOfLastWord = function (s) {
    var words = s.split(" ");
    var len = words.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (len == 1){
            var last_element = words[0];
        }
        else {
            var last_element = words[len - 1];
        }
    return last_element.length;    
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work well if

```
s = 'a '
```

or

```
s = 'Hello.'
```

How to write substring to remove everything except characters?

Comment: Try [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) or [`trimEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd) - and what do you mean by "characters"? Only alphabetic characters?

Comment: Also, your loop isn't doing anything, you can just `if (words.length) { let last_element = words[words.length - 1];}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to try the following code:

```
s = 'Hello. '
s.trim();
```

The `trim()` function removes all whitespaces from your String.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace charachters those are not in `a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9`. or simply just use `\W` in regex expression :

```js
   var last_element = words[len - 1].replace(/\W/g, "");
```